# ODatabaseException: Database instance is not set in current thread while dropping database

Tags: java, database, connection-pooling, orientdb

I'm trying to use OrientDB connection pool, but when I run my code, it fails with an ODatabaseException in the tearDown method:

```
 com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database instance is not set in current thread. Assure to set it with: ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db);
```

This is my code:

```
package com.orientdb.demo.repository.object;

import com.orientdb.demo.domain.Author;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collections;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ObjectAuthorRepositoryTest {

    private OObjectDatabaseTx db;
    private MyObjectAuthorRepository repository = new MyObjectAuthorRepository();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("memory:test");

        if (db.exists()) {
            db.open("admin", "admin");
        } else {
            db.create();
        }

        db.setAutomaticSchemaGeneration(true);
        db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClasses("com.orientdb.demo.domain");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        db.drop();      // <--- this fails
    }

    @Test
    public void testCount() {

        db.save(new Author("Erik", Collections.emptyList()));

        assertEquals(1, repository.count());
    }
}

class MyObjectAuthorRepository {

    private final OPartitionedDatabasePool pool;

    public MyObjectAuthorRepository() {
        pool = new OPartitionedDatabasePool("memory:test", "admin", "admin");
    }

    public long count() {
        try (OObjectDatabaseTx db = new OObjectDatabaseTx(pool.acquire())) {
            return db.countClass(Author.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `MyObjectAuthorRepository` is not of the type `@Repository`.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you talking about types or annotations? How is this relevant to my issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this modification:

```
@After
public void tearDown()
{
    db.activateOnCurrentThread();
    db.drop();      
}
```